# wx.grid does not update number of rows

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to update a wx.grid.PyGridTableBase by calling grid.ForceRefresh() after the table data had been changed. However, the number of rows does not get refreshed and so the table is still showing the original (before update) number of rows. Is there anything I can do to completely update the grid?

Comment: If you can create a very small runnable sample of your code which demonstrates the problem on as little lines as possible it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to notify the grid of the changes you made. You can find an example in the wxPython demo or you can just read this old thread on the topic:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/wxpython-users/z4iobAKq0os/zzUL70WzL_AJ

Which says:

```
msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(self,          # The table
      wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_ROWS_APPENDED, # what we did to it
      1                                       # how many
      )
```

or

```
msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(self,          # The table
      wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_ROWS_INSERTED, # what we did to it
      5,                                      # from which row
      1                                       # how many
      )
```

or

```
msg = wx.grid.GridTableMessage(self,          # The table
      wx.grid.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_ROWS_DELETED,  # what we did to it
      5,                                      # from which row
      1                                       # how many
      )
```

followed by

```
self.GetView().ProcessTableMessage(msg)
```

You can also read about this on the wxPython wiki: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGrid

Comment: I think that's it. I'm not calling any of these methods. Since I don't keep track of what changed, is there a way of saying 'something changed' (row added, row deleted, content changed) and it will refresh completely?

Comment: I'm not sure how the data changes. If it changes on the backend, then you'll just want to use a wx.Timer to do a check of some sort or a refresh. If the user has updated the grid itself, then you should be able to detect that with EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE

Comment: It's changed through some user interaction. Let's say the table displays files of a directory and the user selected a different directory. There could be more files, less files, different file names, etc. I wouldn't necessarily know what changed. Is there a way to say the whole grid data is invalid, so the table is refreshing entirely?

Comment: See the ResetView method in https://bitbucket.org/driscollis/mousevspython/src/3f5ff00ce6f3/wxpython_by_example/grids/gridTableBaseEx.py

Comment: I copied the code into my table. However, I don't see where `getGrid()` and the local variable `grid` are defined in `ResetView`. Executing the method as part of my table throws an exception `AttributeError: "'Table' object has no attribute 'getGrid'"`.

Comment: This is quite an awful design, you'd think it would just request the number of rows from the wxGridTableBase.